# Fade a specific node in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to highlight a specific node by filtering it first.

Below is my code to filter.

```
nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.id == 0; }).style("opacity", 0);
```

Filter function is behaving perfect and returning the node but its not fading.

Below is the node returned by filter function.

```
[{"id":0,"reflexive":false,"nodeName":"New Node","neo4jNodeId":0,"nodeSavedToDatabase":false,"x":319.9250445579969,"y":190.41225493101172,"index":0,"weight":0,"px":319.9249604369836,"py":190.4127175965849}]
```

I would love to have help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The filter result node you mentioned in the question is just an object and not a d3 selection. `style` method will work only for d3 selections. Ensure `nodes` is not just an array of objects but the array of d3 selections of nodes.